# How can i send multiple data as an object to parent component from child component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, two-way-binding

From child component i want to pass some data in parent component. And based on the data also want to update the state of parent component. 
I tried in below way. But every time i am changing the input field updatedPostHandler() is getting called. Which was supposed to get called only on button click.

**Parent component:**

```
class Blog extends Component {
state = {
    posts: [],
    selectedPostId: null
};

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then(response => {
            const posts = response.data.slice(0, 3);
            const updatedPosts = posts.map((post) => {
                return {
                    ...post,
                    author: 'Tanvir'
                }
            });
            this.setState({ posts: updatedPosts })
        });
}

selectedPostHandler = (id) => {
    this.setState({ selectedPostId: id })
};

updatedPostsHandler = (post) => {
    // axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/', post)
    //     .then(response => {
    //     }
    // );
    console.log(post);

}

render() {
    const posts = this.state.posts.map(
        post => <Post
            key={post.id}
            title={post.title}
            author={post.author}
            clicked={() => this.selectedPostHandler(post.id)} />
    );
    return (
        <div>
            <section className="Posts">
                {posts}
            </section>
            <section>
                <FullPost id={this.state.selectedPostId} />
            </section>
            <section>
                <NewPost
                    newPostCreated={this.updatedPostsHandler} />
            </section>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

**Child component:**

```
class NewPost extends Component {
state = {
    title: '',
    content: '',
    author: 'Max',
    post: ''
}

handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        post: {
            title: this.state.title,
            content: this.state.content,
            author: this.state.author
        }
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="NewPost">
            <h1>Add a Post</h1>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <label>Content</label>
            <textarea rows="4" name="content" value={this.state.content} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <label>Author</label>
            <select name="author" value={this.state.author} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <option value="Max">Max</option>
                <option value="Manu">Manu</option>
            </select>
            <button
                onClick={this.props.newPostCreated(this.state.post)}>
                Add Post
            </button>
        </div>

    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write it as :

```
onClick={() => this.props.newPostCreated(this.state.post)}>
```

Otherwise it is getting executed inside the JSX `{..}` everytime the time `render()` is called when doing `setState(..)`. Better is write it without the *arrow* function way for performance reason.

```
class NewPost extends Component {
  // ..
  onBtnClick = () => {
    this.props.newPostCreated(this.state.post);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      // ..
        <button onClick={this.onBtnClick}>Add Post</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I also find your state construction and handleChange function a bit weird and wrong. I will write the class like:

```
class NewPost extends Component {
  state = {
    post: {
      title: "",
      content: "",
      author: "Max"
    }
  };

  handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      post: {
        ...prevState.post,
        [target.name]: target.value
      }
    }));
  };

  onBtnClick = () => {
    this.props.newPostCreated(this.state.post);
  };

  render() {
    const { post: { content, title, author } } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="NewPost">
        <h1>Add a Post</h1>
        <label>Title</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="title"
          value={title}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <label>Content</label>
        <textarea
          rows="4"
          name="content"
          value={content}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <label>Author</label>
        <select
          name="author"
          value={author}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        >
          <option value="Max">Max</option>
          <option value="Manu">Manu</option>
        </select>
        <button onClick={this.onBtnClick}>Add Post</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot. This is working. handleChange function is more appropriate now. But will you please explain why  you added ' () =>  ' arrow function symbol before calling 'newPosCreated'? It  will help me to understand the concept clearly.

Comment: `() => this.props.newPostCreated(this.state.post)` is arrow function expression, which will be called each time you pressed the button. `() => this.props.newPostCreated(this.state.post)` is like `function () { this.props.newPostCreated(this.state.post) }`. But they are not same ofcourse. `this` works differently in this 2 styles. Is this what you asked?

Answer (score -1):

You should add your `updatedPostsHandler` call as an function to your child component. So when you click the button on your child component it calls a function which executes a function.

Try adding your updatedPostsHandler as following:

```
<NewPost newPostCreated={() => this.updatedPostsHandler} />
```

Comment: Not working. I am getting  ''  Proxy {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, isPropagationStopped: ƒ, _dispatchListeners: ƒ, …}  ''